# Call outlook macro from code

Tags: vba, vb.net, outlook

I get an error when I run the `InvokeMember` method below. The error is `UNKNOWN NAME`. I have checked the spelling and it is correct. In `Outlook` I have `Enable Macros` in the trust center. Is there anything I might be missing to get this working? Thanks

VB code:

```
olApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run", Reflection.BindingFlags.Default Or 
                                    Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMember, 
                                    Nothing, olApp, New Object() {"nameOfMacro"})
```

[Research](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306683/)

Comment: Why do you need to run VBA macro from a managed code? Why don't you implement all the functionality inplace?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, I am new to this and did not realize that at first. If you read below can can see I did just that - so what was the point of your comment?

Comment: Why do you need to call a VBA macro instead of implementing the required functionality in the managed code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems `InvokeMember` will not work. The answer is to make the code as you would in the macro and run that. Example:

```
Private Sub MoveAttachmentToFolder()
  Dim olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Dim subFolderA = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("subFolderA")
  Dim subFolderB = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("subFolderB")
  For Each mi As Outlook.MailItem In subFolderA.Items
    If mi.Attachments.Count = 1 Then
      'remember interops use 1 based arrays not zero
      Dim fileName As String = "some path" & mi.Attachments(1).FileName
      mi.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile(fileName)
      mi.Move(subFolderB)
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```